# Can a freemarker interpolation contain an interpolation?

Tags: variables, nested, interpolation, freemarker, namevaluecollection

Let's say I have Freemarker variable A that contains the name of another variable on the hash tree, say. "B." I'd like to use a to read the value of B so, for example, if B contained "C" I could tell Freemarker to output C using A: `${${A}}`
should result in the output of "C". Naturally, this doesn't work in Freemarker, but is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

Use the .vars special variable, which is a hash (map) of the
variables, and hence you can use the aHash[aKeyExpression] syntax:

`${.vars[A]}`

via Daniel Dekany, documentation author & maintainer