# Freemarker variable definition referencing another variable

Tags: interpolation, freemarker

I'm using Freemarker (FMPP) to customize a text file.  I want to have a properties file defining the interpolation data as follows:

```
VAR1=some-value
VAR2=${VAR1}
```

This is highly simplified from my actual files but retains the essence of my use-case.  The template contains a reference of the form `${VAR2}`, which I expect to result in `some-value` being interpolated.  Instead, the interpolated value is the literal `${VAR1}`.

Note that this is not the same as [Can a freemarker interpolation contain an interpolation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648933), which refers to using a variable's value as the name of a variable (indirect reference).  Also, the solution to [can freemarker do second replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131093) involves modifying the template.  I'd like the substitution to happen conceptually 'before' the template is processed so the template can refer only to `${VAR2}` and not need to be aware of the double interpolation.

Is there a way to accomplish this in FreeMarker?

If not, can anybody tell me if Velocity will do this easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the variables that you refer to in the `.properties` file always coming from the same `.properties` file? If so, then you could just write a custom FMPP `DataLoader` that does all the substitution you need, right when the file is loaded. (Or, the `tdd` data-loader can also achieve something similar using `get(varname)` and maybe some `eval(...)`-s, but that's probably too verbose for this purpose.)

As of solving this on the template-language level, it would require that the output of a `${...}` is re-interpreted as a template fragment, and then I assume the out of that too, until there's nothing in the output that looks like a template language construct. I don't know about any template language that does this. However, it's solvable in FreeMarker if the strings where this is required are wrapped with a custom `TemplateScalarModel` implementation that does this repeated evaluation whenever something reads the value of the string. (To use such a custom `TemplateModel` in FMPP, you need a custom FMPP data-loader too, which will wrap the strings in this special way before returning them to FMPP.)

Comment: That's what I thought, and I've come to the same conclusion.  I worked up a two-step solution that processes the properties variables as a template first (to substitute the external parameters) and then as input to a second transformation on the 'real' template.